# why do i get a syntax error in this java project?

Tags: java, database, postgresql

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectingSQL {

    public Connection connection(String dbname, String user, String pass){
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"+dbname,user,pass);
            if(conn!=null){
                System.out.println("Connection Established");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Connection failed.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void createTable(Connection conn, String table_name){
        Statement statement;
        try{
        //the problem is here
            String query ="CREATE TABLE "+ table_name+" (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(100), last_name VARCHAR(100), phone_number int(50), departament_code int(20), email_address VARCHAR(200), password VARCHAR(50))";
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println("Table created");
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first time trying to connect a database to my java project so i tried to follow a youtube video and even though i followed it exactly i get this error: syntax error at or near "(", i tried to change everything around it but i still get the same error.

Comment: Where in the code are you getting that error?

Comment: The code you posted compiles fine

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  I just edited the code block, sorry i did not said it the first time where the problem is and thank you.

Comment: @MsLaus ok, so this is a runtime error you're getting in your query. I see no call to the `createTable` method in your code, so please post a [example]. By the way, chances are you're passing an empty `table_name`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i did call it , but i didnt post it because i did not wanted the code to be too long

Comment: To verify the generated SQL statement you could add `System.out.println(query);` to your `createTable()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is in your query, even though I don't see a call to the `createTable` method in the code you posted.

Remove the length parameters from `int` as they are not accepted in PostgreSQL. Simply use `int` instead of `int(n)`.

Comment: the problem was indeed the length parameters from int, thank you very much for your help!